# "formatted" C language

Tags: c

I want to know what is meant by formatted in the `printf` and `scanf` functions of the C language. I am new to C programming and did not understand what is meant by formatted. Can anyone please give me the appropriate explanation?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152548/formatted-and-unformatted-input-and-output-and-streams)

Comment: Check [printf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/) and [scanf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/).

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s %d", "abc", 123);`

`%s %d` is the format string and contains instructions for what to do with the arguments.  In this case, it says print string, print a space, then print an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As in formatted output
So you can 'print' say a double called myMoney of 11003.145 as $11,003.15.

Comment: For the record this example is an awful idea, you don't really want an invoice or transaction being driven by how `printf` decides to round a double.  Not that a double can store `11003.145` precisely anyway.

Comment: For the record. That wasn't the question was it! PS the word you were looking for was accurately....

Comment: That's why I posted the comment without downvoting.  You answered the question properly but as a side-effect encouraged a bad practice, and from my POV it's good to put this caveat so users reading this answer understand to avoid this pitfall when dealing with formatting money.

Comment: Point taken. Agreed only a muppet would use a double to store money anyway.