# Input Validation on Array

Tags: c++, arrays, validation

I am attempting to input validate a user's value. Criteria: The value inputted cannot be a negative number, in my case the error is encountered when a user enters the wrong value, but instead if reattempting to input the value in the same element it skips over to the next element in the array.

```
string months[NUM_MONTHS] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

int consumption[NUM_MONTHS]; // consumption array

int count; // loop counter

do
{
    for (count = 0; count < NUM_MONTHS; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the CCF consumed for " << months[count] << ": ";

        cin >> consumption[count];

        if (consumption[count] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error: Consumption cannot be a negative integer!" << endl;
        }
    }
} while (consumption[count] < 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the right idea, but your loops are the wrong way round. The loop that checks for a negative number should be the inner loop, not the outer loop.

Here's the correct code

```
for (int count = 0; count < NUM_MONTHS; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter the CCF consumed for " << months[count] << ": ";

    do
    {
        cin >> consumption[count];

        if (consumption[count] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error: Consumption cannot be a negative integer!" << endl;
        }
    } while (consumption[count] < 0);
}
```

Personally I would simplify this, I don't like the fact that this code checks for a negative number twice. Here's how I would do it

```
for (int count = 0; count < NUM_MONTHS; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter the CCF consumed for " << months[count] << ": ";

    // loop until a non-negative number is entered
    for (;;)
    {
        cin >> consumption[count];
        // check number
        if (consumption[count] >= 0)
            break; // non-negative number, quit the loop
        // print error message and try again
        cout << "Error: Consumption cannot be a negative integer!" << endl;
    }
}
```

But this is a style issue, not everyone will agree with me.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly. Data input and validation looks like a simple task. But, unfortunately, in C++ it is astonishingly a notoriously difficult task.

This, because many people do not understand the differences between formatted and non-formatted input in the resulting consequences. You may read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152548/formatted-and-unformatted-input-and-output-and-streams) on SO about it.

What we need to check here is:

1. Did the IO operation work (This check should always been done)
2. Check, if the number is positive

Part 2 is simple. We can achieve this check with a comparison expression.

---

Part 1 is a bit more complicated. You never know what the user will input. He could for example enter the string "abc".

Then the IO function using the extraction operator ">>" would fail. How can we detect that? Fortunately, the C++ IO Stream library will help us.

Streams have a state. And depending on operations, the stream's state will be set accordingly.

You will find a real good overview in the CPP-Reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). Please especially look at the table at the bottom.

Next, how can we check those state bits? You could for example directly check the flags that you are interested in. But, in order to make things easier for you, there are 2 convenience operators for you.

- The [bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) operator, which will return true, if everything was OK
- The [!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) operator, which will be true, if there was an error

How can this be used? You could for example check the successful input operation be writing:

```
if (std::cin >> consumption[monthIndex]) {  . . . .
```

But why does this work? You may have read that the inserter and extraction operators return a reference to the stream with which they were called. This allows chaining IO operations, like for example: `std::cout<<a<<b<<c;`.

So, if the above expression `std::cin >> consumption[monthIndex]` is executed, it will try to read and format the integer and the return a reference to `std::cin`. The `if` statement would then look like `if (std::cin)`, and, since an `if` statement expects a boolean value, the `bool` function of the stream will be called and returns true or false.

---

Good, understood. Now we will add the range check:

```
if ((std::cin >> consumption[monthIndex]) and (consumption[monthIndex] > 0))
```

And, we will take advantage of boolean shortcut evaluation in boolean expressions. Only if the extraction operation `>>` was successful (the `bool` function returned `true`), then the comparison will be executed. If the input operation was already `false`, then the comparison will not be done. This will prevent comparison with some indeterminate value. Cool.

Please note. If any failure bit of the stream is set, we must [clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) it. So, please call this functions, if there was a problem. Otherwise you can never read again.

An additional caveat. If the user enters "abc" the letters 'a', 'b' and 'c' will not be consumed, because they cannot be converted to an integer. So, they are still in the input buffer. If you would now continue to try to read integers in a loop, you would always get again the "abc" and run into an endless loop. Because of that, we need to clear the input buffer and can use the streams [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function for that.

Then, you can read one integer in a loop, until you get a valid input. In an outer loop, you can then read the values for a month.

This could look like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int NumberOfMonths = 12;
std::string months[NumberOfMonths] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

int main() {

    int consumption[NumberOfMonths]{};

    for (int monthIndex = 0; monthIndex < NumberOfMonths; ++monthIndex) {

        bool inputIsValid{};
        while (not inputIsValid) {

            std::cout << "Please enter the consumed CCF for '" << months[monthIndex] << "': ";

            if ((std::cin >> consumption[monthIndex]) and (consumption[monthIndex] > 0))
                inputIsValid = true;
            else {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                std::cout << "\nError: Invalid Input\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The last thing to optimize is to use more C++ language elements. In C++ we do not use C-Style arrays that much and also more appropriate data types. Repeating operations can be put in functions, which will make the code more readable.

I will show you an example, how you could perhaps implement a solution by using more modern "C++".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std::string_literals;

// Get a positive intger from std::cin and handle errors
int getPositiveInteger() {

    // This will hold the read value
    int result{};

    // Here we will store, if the input is valid or not
    bool inputIsValid{};

    // As long as the input is not valid (which will be true for the first loop run)
    while (not inputIsValid) {

        // Give instruction for the user
        std::cout << "Please enter a positive intger: ";

        // Read and check
        if ((std::cin >> result) and (result > 0))
            // OK, we got a valid input. We can terminate the loop
            inputIsValid = true;
        else {
            // There was a problem
            // Clear potentially set error bits of the stream
            std::cin.clear();   
            // Delete potential existing remaining characters from the input buffer
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            // And, show some error message
            std::cout << "\nError: Invalid Input\n\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Define month names
const std::vector month{ "January"s, "February"s, "March"s, "April"s, "May"s, "June"s, "July"s, "August"s, "September"s, "October"s, "November"s, "December"s };

int main() {

    // Here we will store the consumption per month
    std::vector<int>consumption(month.size());

    // Get values for all months
    for (std::size_t index{}; int& c : consumption) {

        // User instruction
        std::cout << "\n\nEnter data for month '" << month[index++] << "'\n";

        // Read and assign interger value
        c = getPositiveInteger();
    }
}
```